# Is there a way i could speed up my work?

Tags: materials, node-editor, lighting, osx

I'm macbook pro 18 user and complete beginner. I thought my computer can handle Blender 2.82 but I couldn't even add materials on my project. On view mode eevee works fine but on cycles it just stop working. How do I speed up my process?[image: My working project]

Comment: The performance will depend on 3 things, your CPU, available RAM and if you have a GPU. What do you have here?

Comment: My GPU isn't working on cycles since Mac has AMD  I'm trying to make a talking burger animation here, looks like my 3D dream is done untill I get PC 